# How to display more than one month in MonthCalendar on run avb.net

Tags: vb.net, monthcalendar

I'm trying to display more than one month on run using MonthCalendar, I set the property of CalendarDimensions Width = 1, Height = 2, but after run it gets back to one month only.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your use was correct, you should set the [CalendarDimensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa983604(v=VS.71).aspx) property. Make sure there is enough room on the form for the new dimension though.

[image]

This  will display 2 columns and 2 rows of MonthCalendars, provided there is enough room.

Comment: You can also anchor the calendar in ways to allow it to change the number of months shown as the user changes the form size.